# Mockito Android Unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, dagger-2

I have MVP in my application. Presenter has interface

```
public interface ILoginPresenter<V> extends Presenter<V> {
    void logUserIn(String email, String password, String deviceToken, String deviceType); 
}
```

Realization has RX Single

```
 mLoginSubscription = mModel.logUserIn(email, password, deviceToken, deviceType)
            .compose(RxUtil.setupNetworkSingle())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Timber.i("Log in complete");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Timber.e(e, "Retrofit could not get User.");

                    getView().dismissProgressDialog();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(UserResponseRetrofit response) {
                    Timber.i("Retrofit is attempting to get User");
                    mSaveModel.saveUser(user);
                    getView().dismissProgressDialog();
                    getView().goToMenuActivity();
                }
            });
```

Also i have module for Dagger

```
@Module
public class ModelModule {
    @Provides
    @ScreenScope
    public ILoginModel provideLoginModel(LoginModel p) {
        return p;
    }
}
```

My unit test look like next:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, manifest = "/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
public class LoginPresenterTest {

    public static final String SOME_OTHER_TOKEN = "someOtherToken";
    private AppComponent mAppComponent;
    private LoginComponent mLoginComponent;
    private ILoginView mockView;
    private ModelModule mockModel;
    private ILoginPresenter mLoginPresenter;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // Creating the mocks
        mockView = Mockito.mock(ILoginView.class);
        mockModel = Mockito.mock(ModelModule.class);

        ILoginModel mock = Mockito.mock(ILoginModel.class);
        User urr = Mockito.mock(User.class);
        Mockito.when(mockModel.provideLoginModel(null)).thenReturn(mock);
        Mockito.when(mock.logUserIn("", "", "", "")).thenReturn(ScalarSynchronousSingle.just(urr));

        mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(RuntimeEnvironment.application))
                .build();

        mLoginComponent = DaggerLoginComponent.builder()
                .appComponent(mAppComponent)
                .modelModule(mockModel)
                .presenterModule(new PresenterModule())
                .build();

        mLoginPresenter = mLoginComponent.provideLoginPresenter();
        mLoginPresenter.setView(mockView);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin() {
        mLoginPresenter.logUserIn("", "", "", "");
        try {
            java.lang.Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Mockito.verify(mockView).dismissProgressDialog();
    }
```

So using Dagger I need to build Presenter correctly. For this purposes, I am trying to use Mockito.when. Firstly look like this line doesn't work

```
Mockito.when(mockModel.provideLoginModel(null)).thenReturn(mock);
```

The target purpose is to use my own Model realization which return Single.

don't really understand why my mock of ModelModule doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? Do you mean it is not returning your mock? Are you sure dagger is calling `provideLoginModel` with the argument `null`? If you don't care about the argument do `Mockito.when(mockModel.provideLoginModel(any())).thenReturn(mock);`

Comment: Thank you `any()` - is answer for few other my questions

Comment: Great I updated my answer to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a test module out of your production `Module`?

See how they suggest to do testing via Dagger [in official site](https://google.github.io/dagger/testing.html).

```
@Module
public class ModelModuleTest extends ModelModule {

    @Override
    public ILoginModel provideLoginModel(LoginModel p) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can pass mocked dependency to your `Module`.

Comment: yes, i did so, but actually my module should fully override originall one, because Dagger will create LoginModel any way. and then i return stub one

Comment: What the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

The issue may be that you are mocking will *null*. In that case `mockModel` will *only* return mock when `provideLoginModel` is called with *null*

```
Mockito.when(mockModel.provideLoginModel(null)).thenReturn(mock);   
mockModel.provideLoginModel(null) // returns mock
mockModel.provideLoginModel(new Foo()) // returns null
```

Instead you can use a matcher such as `any()`:

```
Mockito.when(mockModel.provideLoginModel(any())).thenReturn(mock);   
mockModel.provideLoginModel(null) // returns mock
mockModel.provideLoginModel(new Foo()) // also returns null
```

to return `mock` on any call.

**BIG PICTURE**
For unit testing I would suggest not using Dagger, instead use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` you only need the object you are testing to be real the rest can be mocks.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, manifest = "/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
public class LoginPresenterTest {

    public static final String SOME_OTHER_TOKEN = "someOtherToken";

    @Mock
    ILoginView mockView;

    @Mock
    SomePresenterDependency somePresenterDependency

    @InjectMocks
    ILoginPresenter mLoginPresenter;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.injectMocks(this);

        mLoginPresenter.setView(mockView);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin() {
        mLoginPresenter.logUserIn("", "", "", "");
        try {
            java.lang.Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Mockito.verify(mockView).dismissProgressDialog();
    }
}
```

If you are doing integration testing and need multiple real objects you could just create an inner/anonymous module for your component that returns the desired object. (instead of trying to mock the module interface).

Comment: Ok, but presenter use dependencies. How Mockito will know what to add?

Comment: [@InjectMocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.19/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) will use the type and/or name to supply constructor arguments & `@Inject`/`@Autowire` annotated members. Change `SomePresenterDependency` to the dependency you are providing via Dagger.

Comment: My question more about why Already created mock couldn't be modified like that Mockito.when(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getString(R.string.check_credentials)).thenReturn("bla");

Comment: @YevgenKulik `RuntimeEnvironment.application` is not a Mockito mock, it's a Robolectric fake. So you can't stub it with `Mockito.when()`

Comment: How about to do it `likeRuntimeEnvironment.application =  spy(RuntimeEnvironment.application)` and then redefine it with when? or I don't correctly understand spy?